# Javascript: How do I add a top bar to a short url?

Tags: javascript, short-url

I've been trying to understand how is possible to develop a bit.ly  style URL shortener which also adds a bar to the website.

For example: http://om.ly/BSdZu

There's a group on twitter that shares all their URLs starting with "om.ly" and they have a top bar in each of the URLs they share.

How is that done? I imagine is with JavaScript but how? Also, is there any service you know that does that so I can understand how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in 2 ways (at least):

- via framesets -- not recommended as it's old style; but you can set the top frame to display your toolbar and the bottom frame set the url to the page
- via iframes -- have your url load a page from your website which shows to iframes: the top one is your toolbar and you display in it whatever you want, and the bottom one you set the url to the long url. This is how bit.ly, linkedin and many others do it.

Comment: What about CSS??? I'm sure that bit.ly and linkedin don't, anyway. Nobody uses tables of frames for layout anymore.

Comment: Does bit.ly adds the toolbar as well? I never saw that.

Comment: it does if you're logged into bit.ly -- i have an account with them and i see the toolbar sometimes. I'm guessing that's when they add it -- or maybe it's triggered by some script on a page ?

Comment: @Loozah you're right -- no one uses frames anymore, which is why i pointed that out. It still works though, which is why I still included it in my answer, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Anonymous you need a frameset/iframe to pull the linked url. This have nothing to do with layouts

Comment: @Mauricio: If i'm correct, to use frames to do this, your would also have to put the content in a frame as well. When I said "Layout", I meant the look of a page in general.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by

```
 position: fixed;
```

see [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/HTMLCSS/Layout/Fixedtopfooterandleftbar.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different methods, but my preferred method would be to make a `DIV` field, and tell it to float: [example code here](http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/fixed_menu.html)

**EDIT**

Here's the basic code you need:

```
    <div id="fixeddiv" style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:50px;right:10px;top:10px;padding:16px;background:#FFFFFF;border:2px solid #2266AA">  
    This is a (Javascript/CSS) Fixed menu.  
    </div>
```

Comment: problem is -- how do you insert that div on a page that's loaded from another server (not yours)?